# Generating auto XML in BizTalk Orchestration

Tags: xml, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I want to generate an XML in BizTalk Orchestration Start point. I mean at Orchestration start I want an XML to be automatically generated and process starts. Actually this will be a "PING" type of thing which will be calling some service frequently.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please be more specific?

Triggering a BizTalk orchestration 'by itself' at a specific time / time interval (without an incoming message) [requires a workaround](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/3734729d-9361-44e0-80f9-785828c24f77/) - the [BizTalk Scheduled Task Adapter](http://www.codeplex.com/BizTalkScheduledTask) is usually a good option here.

(And assuming your Ping Service is downstream from BizTalk) - Creating a 'static' message to send as a request to your 'ping' service [has also been](http://blog.sabratech.co.uk/2008/03/creating-message-from-scratch.html) [covered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313269/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-new-message-within-a-biztalk-orchestration). The easiest option could be to use the dummy trigger message above (which activates the orchestration) as the source schema in a Map, and then just set constant values into your 'ping' message.

Comment: Yes BizTalk Scheduled Task Adapter has done my work in sample project. But in real project I was unable to implement it. I am getting following two errors:

Comment: Your errors didn't post - can you repost your comment or edit your post plz?

Comment: Thanks I have resolved that my self. That were some binding errors I unbind receive ports in orchestration and deployed the project successfully then bind them again.