# How to set value in expression for scheme in BizTalk orchestration?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations, biztalk-schemas

When I want to compile, an error shown

```
use of unconstructed message
```

My code for expression is:

```
Message_2.Approved == false
```

XML code in scheme **Article.xsd**:

```
  <xs:element name="Approved">
  <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:boolean" /> 
  </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

**Message_2** is assigned to assigned to a **Send** shape.

And **Message Type** of **Message_2** is **BizTalk_Server_Project7.Article** .

Comment: Have never worked with `biztalk`, but maybe the error is because of the typo in `Artcile`?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with Article. Article is an XML scheme which is used into expression. My problem is to set the value to this part of Article.

Comment: I know of `Article`, but in your post it says `ArtCile`. If you copy-pasted it, maybe that is the source of your error.

Comment: Is that the entire source of the Expression Shape?  There is no 'if'.

Comment: Is your code `Message_2.Article.Approved = false;` in an Expression Shape or in a Rule for Decision Shape?  If it is a rule decision shape it should be `Message_2.Article.Approved == false` That is = should be == and no ; (semicolon)

Comment: @Johns-305  In BizTalk you can't have an If in an Expression Shape.  To achieve If logic in an Orchestration you need to use a Decision Shape in which you enter a boolean expression for each rule.

Comment: Try using `!Message_2.Article.Approved`  If that still gives the same error it means that it isn't actually a Boolean and there is something wrong with your distinguished field.   And please answer if it is an Expression or a Decision shape.  And are you trying to set the value as per your comment #2 or read it?

Comment: The `Message Type` of `Message2` is `BizTalk_Server_Project7.Article`.

Comment: This code is correct: `Message_2.Approved==false` but when I compile the project an error shown as **use of unconstructed message 'Message_2'**

Comment: @Bahman.  As you aren't answering the questions being asked of you it is very hard for us to determine what the issues are, especially as you seem now to be encountering a new problem.  Please update your question with more details or if it is a new problem start a new question.   The use of unreconstructed message means you are probably trying to assign to a message outside of a Construct Message shape, or you haven't created the message in the Construct Message shape yet.  The fact that you are getting an error message means that your code is not correct.

Comment: Ok! I updated. I assigned to a Send shape.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is something wrong with your property promotion.

You are trying to use 'Approved' as a distinguished field in your expression shape to set a value, which is perfect use of a distinguished field. Please review [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560697(v=bts.20).aspx) on MSDN if you did everything right.

Comment: Still anything doesn't change.

Comment: This code is correct: `Message_2.Approved==false` but when I compile the project an error shown as **use of unconstructed message 'Message_2'**

Comment: When you are trying to assing values to a message, you must do this from within a contruct message shape where you define the message that you are about to change. You can checkout the following thread about the ways of creating messages in an orchestration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313269/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-new-message-within-a-biztalk-orchestration

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the used property is promoted or distinguished before can be used in your orchestration's expression shape. if your property will be used only in messagebox context and not outside(filters or pipelines) you can make simple and use distiguished field.

Comment: Still anything doesn't change.

Comment: your conditional if is "Message_2.Article.Approved = false" ?

Comment: Yes, in rule shape for expression I wrote this.

Comment: and The `Message Type` of `Message2` is `BizTalk_Server_Project7.Article`.

Comment: equal test should use double "=" so "Message_2.Article.Approved == false" not "Message_2.Article.Approved = false"

Comment: I have tested before but still with the same error.

Comment: i think there is a problem with your schema, can you give me the code of your schema? i'm trying to create it on a local project to see what exactly the problem

Comment: This code is correct: `Message_2.Approved==false` but when I compile the project an error shown as **use of unconstructed message 'Message_2'**

Comment: this is a new problem?

Comment: Yes. I found the suitable code for expression but compiler doesn't recognize **Message_2** .

Comment: when you open your orchestration view , is there a message named "Message_2" in Messages list?

Comment: Yes, it is available!

Comment: ok greate. Make sure that you use an assignment shape (inside a construct message) when you create Message_2. Then just copy the code in the expression editor (Message_2 = yourinputMessage;)

Comment: I have assigned to Send.